# Interpret GDB/LLDB hex dump of memory

Tags: c, memory, gdb, lldb

Why does GDB print memory in reversed order when grouped to words?

I was interested in how memory looks like and created a basic C struct:

```
typedef struct example_struct {
    char foo[17];
} example_struct;

int main() {
    struct example_struct *address_ptr;

    char char_string[] = "AZZZBZZZCZZZDZZZ";

    address_ptr = (example_struct *) malloc(sizeof(example_struct));
    strcpy(address_ptr->foo, char_string);

    return 1;
}
```

I created a breakpoint at the return statement and used `x/20xb address_ptr` within gdb to show me 20 bytes of the raw memory. It looked exactly like expected:

```
(lldb) x/20xb address_ptr
0x7fbf40500190: 0x41 0x5a 0x5a 0x5a 0x42 0x5a 0x5a 0x5a
0x7fbf40500198: 0x43 0x5a 0x5a 0x5a 0x44 0x5a 0x5a 0x5a
0x7fbf405001a0: 0x00 0x00 0xd7 0xa1
```

However, when using `x/5xw` (which groups the memory into words, 4 bytes per block, 5 times 4 bytes equals also 20 bytes), I encountered something odd:

```
(lldb) x/5xw address_ptr
0x7fbf40500190: 0x5a5a5a41 0x5a5a5a42 0x5a5a5a43 0x5a5a5a44
0x7fbf405001a0: 0xa1d70000
```

***Every block has to be read from right to left. Why is that?***

Is this correct, and when: why is the reading direction when 4 bytes are grouped together reversed? Since the memory on the most common architectures is byte-addressable (as is mine), I think the reversed representation is not how it is actually stored in memory, is it?

Just was wondering, maybe someone may enlighten me, why gdb does this and why only when printing hex in four bytes per block and why the order is not reversed when printed in the ungrouped memory hex format.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: IMHO, endianess has nothing to do with this, as we are talking about a byte array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26456907/3600860
This also does not explain why gdb only reverses order when it prints the bytes as groups of four. Printing bytewise shows the correct order. It seems to be a formatting issue, but I don't understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: ? Yes it has. You are doing `x/5xw`. The memory is displayed using the endianess of your machine.

Comment: `gdb` does not reverse order. The order is not reversed. The order is little endian. The most significant byte of the word is the byte with the greatest address. So when composing a word form bytes, bytes in the memory go `0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04` and the word is `0x04030201`. The order is correct in both times. You can print halfword and giant word too.

Comment: Ah okay. It seems I just have to keep this in mind when formatting and reading hexdumps :)